# Accepting rvalue as lvalue reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, pass-by-reference, rvalue

Consider the following simple program

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void fun(string &s)
{
}


int main()
{
    string str = "Hello";
    fun(str + " world");
    return 0;
}
```

GCC (version 4.7) prints an error in the call to fun, stating that a non-const reference cannot be initialized with an rvalue.

Miscrosoft Visual C++ 2013 compiles the code without complaining (generating, I assume, a reference to a temporary object).

Am I correct in assuming the GCC's behaviour is correct, whereas MSVC is wrong?

Comment: Tip @oz1cz: Always look on the column to the right when posting an answer (_actually_, you should search first). When your question is a duplicate or very similar to another question, you will almost certainly find the duplicate question on the top while you are still typing (it's visible there right now!). This will help avoiding clutter on the site, and save you time.